# using sys_context to match data string

Tags: oracle, view

I'm trying to use data in sys_context form to perform a match in a WHERE clause.

What I put into the context is ('53','89'), which is what is returned when I select against dual.

My where statement is:  where to_char(location_id) in sys_context('my_ctx','valoc')

Since I'm not getting the expected response, I'm guessing that what I think Oracle should see is not actually what it sees, but I don't know how to "look" at what's passed to the processor from TOAD.

The original form was where location_id in sys_context('my_ctx','valoc') with (53,89) in valoc, but that didn't return anything either. I'm sensing there may be no answer to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the resulting `WHERE` clause is equivalent to this:

```
where to_char(location_id) in '('53','89')'
```

(didn't double the inner apostrophes for clarity)

The database sees what's retrieved from context as a single value, not as a list of values.

You can use the `CONNECT BY` trick to achieve your goal:

```
SELECT 1
  FROM dual
WHERE '53' IN ( -- replace '53' with TO_CHAR(location_id)
  SELECT regexp_substr('53,89', '[0-9]*', 1, level) -- replace '53,89' with sys_context('my_ctx','valoc')
    FROM dual
  CONNECT BY regexp_substr('53,89', '[0-9]*', 1, level) IS NOT NULL -- replace '53,89' with sys_context('my_ctx','valoc')
);
```